# AngularJS expression doesn't work in a different view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression, master-detail

So I have this problem with creating a new view. The routeing works just fine because it shows the required HTML perfectly, but the expressions which worked just fine in the main view don't show up in the new.

```
<a href="#/view/{{todo.id}}" id="super" ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter: search">
        <div id="main" ng-class="{'done': todo.done}">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" />
            <span>{{todo.title}}</span>
            <button id="info">i</button>
            <div class="inf">
                <span>Prioritás: {{todo.priority}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="inf" id="sec">
                <span>Határidő: {{todo.deadLine | date: "yyyy. MMMM. dd"}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

These are the expressions in the main view, they work like a charm.

```
myTodoList.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: "mainController"
    })
    .when('/view/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'view.html',
        controller: "mainController"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: ''
    });
```

This is the routeing part, this is working.

```
<div id="mainContent">Master Detail
    <div ng-controller="mainController" ng-view></div>
</div>
```

This is the `div` where the new view goes.

```
<div>
<p>Should be the ID: {{todo.id}}</p>
<p> should be the title: {{todo.title}}</p>
<p> this works: {{1+2}}</p></div>
```

And this is the `view.html`. The third expression is working, so I have the problem with de other two expressions. I think I messed up this because I can't reach the data I want. `todo.id` and `todo.title` are data created by a `function` in real time.

```
$scope.addTodo = function(title, priority, deadLine, id) {
    $scope.todos.push({
        'id': lastId,
        'title': $scope.newTodo,
        'done': false,
        'priority': $scope.newPriority,
        'deadLine': $scope.newDeadLine
    });
    $scope.newTodo = ''
    $scope.newPriority = ''
    $scope.newDeadLine = ''
    lastId++;
}
```

This is the `function` I am using. I hope I described the problem well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem. I needed to separate the different objects. So I made a function.

```
$scope.currentTodo = $scope.todos[0];

$scope.selectTodo = function(todo) {
    $scope.currentTodo = todo;
}
```

I made a div and called this function with it.

```
<div ng-click="selectTodo(todo);" id="super" ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter: search">
```

And the problematic div now looks like this.

```
<div id="mainContent">Master Detail
    <div>
        <p>Should be the ID: {{currentTodo.id}}</p>
        <p> should be the title: {{currentTodo.title}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help! I think both of you helped me through this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `ng-repeat` in your new view ?

```
<div>
<p>Should be the ID: {{todo.id}}</p>
<p> should be the title: {{todo.title}}</p>
<p> this works: {{1+2}}</p></div>
```

Your Scope variable name is `$socpe.todos` but here you are trying to access `todo` make sure if you are inside the `ng-repeat` if this is not your problem then share your full code on fiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Jeyenthaaran Nanjappan said, i think your `div` should look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <p>Should be the ID: {{todo.id}}</p>
    <p> should be the title: {{todo.title}}</p>
    <p> this works: {{1+2}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I try to make it work in codepen, but I can't find the way how to add the 'view.html'.

I tried this. If I put 'ng-repeat="todo in todos"' there the whole view become wanished.

Comment: So Iput ng-repeat="todo in todos" next to the ng-view. It somewhat works. But if I add new "todos" to the list all of the data appears in the same view. What I want to do is if I click on a specific "todo" the master detail div shoud show the data of that spedific object.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues in the nesting of the div and html. Change this:

```
<div id="mainContent">Master Detail
        <div ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-controller="mainController" ng-view></div>
      <p>Should be the ID: {{todo.id}}</p>
    <p> should be the title: {{todo.title}}</p>
    <p> this works: {{1+2}}</p>
    </div>
```

to this:

```
<div id="mainContent">Master Detail
        <div ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-controller="mainController">
      <p>Should be the ID: {{todo.id}}</p>
    <p> should be the title: {{todo.title}}</p>
    <p> this works: {{1+2}}</p>
          </div>
    </div>
```